# How to compile CUDA C files and Nvidia OptiX files inside the same Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, cuda, nvidia, optix

I am currently using the Optix ray tracing engine on Visual Studio. My problem consists of computing data and rendering them with Optix.

I have already written a pure C CUDA program to compute the data, but I cannot integrate it inside my Optix project.

I compiled my Optix project by using the SDK's CMakeLists.txt and modifying it. Any insight on how to make my project compile the C CUDA files (.cu) as well as the Optix Kernels (also .cu) in the same VS project?

Comment: Can you not just add them to the CmakeLists.txt file to compile them?

Comment: Well the Optix .cu files should be compiled into .ptx, while the C CUDA files should be compiled into obj files . That's why some modifications should be done for it to work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a duplicate question to one asked on the official forum for OptiX.  Please see the following link.

http://forums.developer.nvidia.com/devforum/discussion/6656/compile-c-cuda-and-optix-kernels-in-the-same-visual-studio-project

Comment: The link is dead. Should be at least short description of the solution.